# How to get more than 500 issues from SonarQube api

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using the SonarQube API in a java tool to process issues and add comments to them/change the issue status (e.g. wont fix)

The api/issues/search function has a page size limitation of 500 max. I have more than 500 issues and need to read this. I thought of performing mulitpule queries, but the issue keys are not numberical so I can not just increment and perform a query on the next 500.

Is there any way I can handle more than 500 issues from the API? I thought a workaround would be to get the list of issue keys from the api and query in batches, but this doesnt seem possible.

Comment: As a last resort you could query the database.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? How do you decide which issues you need to update ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam I've raised issues from an external tool in Sonarqube using a plugin. I then am trying to perform a few different tasks on these issues. For example the issue from the external tool might be set to "ignore" which loosly maps to SonarQube "wont fix", so I am getting all the sonarqube issues I've raised (filtered on my tag) check the external tool to see if the issue is "ignore" and if so change the sonarqube issue to "wont fix". the problem being I'm limited to getting 500 issues from sonarqube.

Comment: Ok, I've added a response on what I would propose you to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Short answer : no, it's not possible to get more than 500 issues in a single web service call.
- Long answer : you should try to use a [hook](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Hooks) (either by using a plugin or by using a web hook) that is triggered on each project analysis => You'll then be able to browse all project's issues using pagination : `api/issues/search?componentKeys=PROJECT_KEY&ps=500&p=1`, then `api/issues/search?componentKeys=PROJECT_KEY&ps=500&p=2`, etc.

  The total number of items can be found in the response, under "paging" -> "total".

Comment: "total" is the number of ITEMS, not PAGES